# По какой причине из файла с реализацией класса не виден заголовочный файл? (C++ CLI)

Tags: c++, c++-cli, компиляция

Изучаю C++ CLI. Пытаюсь просто создать класс наследующий `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game`, и переопределяющий пару методов.
Создал файл заголовка, вот так:

```
//Game1.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
namespace CLRGame {
    public ref class Game1 : public Microsoft::Xna::Framework::Game
    {
    public:
        Game1();
    private:
        Microsoft::Xna::Framework::GraphicsDeviceManager ^ graphics;
        Microsoft::Xna::Framework::Graphics::SpriteBatch ^spriteBatch;
    protected:
        void Initialize() override;
        void LoadContent() override;
        void UnloadContent() override;
        void Update(Microsoft::Xna::Framework::GameTime ^gameTime) override;
        void Draw(Microsoft::Xna::Framework::GameTime ^gameTime) override;
    };
}
```

Описал реализацию:

```
//Game1.cpp
#include "Game1.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace Microsoft::Xna::Framework;
using namespace Microsoft::Xna::Framework::Graphics;
using namespace Microsoft::Xna::Framework::Design;
using namespace Microsoft::Xna::Framework::Input;

namespace CLRGame {
    Game1::Game1()
    {
        graphics = gcnew GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content->RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    void Game1::Initialize()
    {
        Game::Initialize();
    }

    void Game1::LoadContent()
    {
        Game::LoadContent();
        spriteBatch = gcnew SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    void Game1::UnloadContent()
    {
        Game::UnloadContent();
    }

    void Game1::Update(Microsoft::Xna::Framework::GameTime ^gameTime)
    {
        Game::Update(gameTime);
        KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard::GetState();
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys::Escape)) {
            Exit();
        }
    }

    void Game1::Draw(Microsoft::Xna::Framework::GameTime ^gameTime)
    {
        Game::Update(gameTime);
        GraphicsDevice->Clear(Color::Bisque);

    }
}
```

Короче просто попытался повторить структуру проекта MonoGame (C#) сразу после создания.
Intellisense (VS 2017 Enterprise) ни на что не ругается, однако при попытке скомпилировать это добро получаю тучу ошибок, связанных с тем что из .cpp файла не видно соответствующий .h:
[image: Скриншот из списка ошибок в Visual studio]

Как видно, на первом месте `Ошибка  C2653   Game1: не является именем класса или пространства имен  CLRPP`.
Настройки проекта, компилятора и вообще какие-либо настройки не трогал.
 Структура проекта:
[image: Скриншот обозревателя решений Visual Studio]

Ума не приложу, что делать и с чем это может быть связано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прекомпилированный заголовок `#include "stdafx.h"` следует инклюдить только в единицы трансляци (.cpp файлы), при этом он обязательно должен идти первым, так как все выше него игнорируется. А лучше инклюдить его посредством опции копилятора `/FI"stdafx.h"`

А еще на скриншоте структуры проекта у вас на самом деле структура фильтров проекта, а не файлов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло сразу помогло.